# Querying for owned collection in CosmosDB throws exception when using OData $select (Cannot use ICollection in place of IQueryable)

Tags: entity-framework-core, odata, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-6.0

We are using OData on top of efcore for querying data from CosmosDB (SQL API). The library versions we are using are -

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="8.0.10" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos" Version="6.0.4" />
```

Our $metadata looks as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="SampleIksApi.Models" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <EntityType Name="PartnerTenantSubscriptions">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="id" />
            </Key>
            <Property Name="PartnerMPNId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="PartnerName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="CustomerTenantId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="CustomerTenantName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="ReportingDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="Subscriptions" Type="Collection(SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscription)" />
        </EntityType>
        <ComplexType Name="PartnerTenantSubscription">
            <Property Name="SubscriptionId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="SubscriptionState" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="PaidStartDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
            <Property Name="PaidEndDate" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" />
        </ComplexType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="Container">
            <EntitySet Name="PartnerTenantSubscriptions" EntityType="SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscriptions" />
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Our DbContext setup and EDM Model setup for OData are as follows -

```
var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<PartnerTenantSubscriptions>();
        entity.HasNoDiscriminator();
        modelBuilder.Entity<PartnerTenantSubscriptions>()
            .ToContainer(containerName)
            .HasPartitionKey(x => x.PartnerMPNId);

var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<PartnerTenantSubscriptions>("PartnerTenantSubscriptions");
        return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

This setup works great for regular queries such as simply querying all of the collection or selecting one or more of primitive types such as PartnerName but when I try to select the field 'Subscriptions' which is a collection type, I run into the below error

Query - api/odata/v1.0.0/PartnerTenantSubscriptions?$select=PartnerMPNId,ReportingDate,CustomerTenantId,PartnerAssociationType,CustomerTenantName,Subscriptions
Exception (with full stack trace) -

```
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscription]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscription]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscription] Take[PartnerTenantSubscription](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[SampleIksApi.Models.PartnerTenantSubscription], Int32)' (Parameter 'arg0')
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, String methodParamName, String argumentParamName, Int32 index)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, Expression arg0, Expression arg1)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Update(Expression object, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos.Query.Internal.CosmosQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.Container.TruncatedCollection`1..ctor(IQueryable`1 source, Int32 pageSize, Boolean parameterize)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults[T](IQueryable`1 queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean parameterize, Boolean& resultsLimited)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.LimitResults(IQueryable queryable, Int32 limit, Boolean parameterize, Boolean& resultsLimited)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyPaging(IQueryable result, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, HttpRequest request)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Query.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at SampleIksApi.Common.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__5_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\haridura\source\repos\SampleIksApi\SampleIksApi\Startup.cs:line 37
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I have tried multiple configurations ranging from OwnsMany to setting up ComplexTypes but I cannot seem to get around this issue. Can someone help point me towards what I could be missing here?

Comment: Show exception callstack.

Comment: Updated with full stack trace